# CS50 Pset 1 Cash Issue

Tags: c, cs50

I am brand new and just trying to get this basic code (not the best code possible) to work.  When I run it, it just gives a blank answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float dollars;
    do
    {
        dollars = get_float("Change owed: ");
    } 
    while (dollars <= 0);
        
    int cents = round(dollars * 100);
    int coins = 0;

    while (cents >= 25)
    ;
         {
           cents = cents - 25;
           coins ++;
        }

        while (cents >= 10)
        ;
        {
            cents = cents - 10;
            coins ++;
        }

        while (cents >= 5)
        ;
        {
            cents = cents - 5;
            coins ++;
        }
        while (cents >= 1)
        ;
        {
            cents = cents - 1;
            coins ++;
    }
       printf("I have %i coin(s)\n)", coins);
    
}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hanging here

```
while (cents >= 25)
;
```

A `while` statement is only terminated by a semi-colon `;` when it is part of a do-while loop. That `while` loop is hanging because the value of `cents` never changes (or at least one of the loops is hanging, depending on the amount entered). Remove the `;` from the whiles and see what happens.

Comment: You're weldcome. Be sure to [learn how we say "thank you"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  on SO.